# How to change the order of events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Is it possible to change the order of events to invoke alert function with message `Huh?` first and only then next alert with 'Yeah!' message?

```
<div class="elem" onclick="alert('Yeah!')"></div>
```

My jQuery code.

```
$('.elem').click(function () {
    alert('Huh?');
})
```

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/84Lyq3n9/

Comment: If you only use .click(), its quite easy http://jsfiddle.net/84Lyq3n9/1/

Comment: But I cannot remove inline event `onclick`. So maybe there is another elegant approach?

Comment: Can you change the value of onclick? You can refer it to a custom function that calls both alerts in whatever order you like.

Comment: No, I cannot. Although I can only change jQuery code.

Comment: If using JQuery or any other framework, please don't forget about the tag. I added it for you. (You know, so people don't loose time on topics they don't really care about)

Comment: Well, I'll consider it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var inline_click_handler_src = $('.elem').attr('onclick');
var inline_click_handler = new Function('e', inline_click_handler_src);
$('.elem').removeAttr('onclick');

$('.elem').click(function () {
    alert('Huh?');
    inline_click_handler();
});
```

[Edit] Or without mucking with markup content:

```
var el = $('.elem').get(0);
var inline_click_handler = el.onclick;
el.onclick = null;

$('.elem').click(function () {
    alert('Huh?');
    inline_click_handler();
});
```

[One more edit] In case your inline click handler uses `this`, use `function.call()`, to set the execution context:

```
var el = $('.elem').get(0);
var inline_click_handler = el.onclick;
el.onclick = null;

$('.elem').click(function () {
    alert('Huh?');
    inline_click_handler.call(el);
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. But maybe there is an option without attribute removing (`$('.elem').removeAttr('onclick')`)?

Comment: Looks like it's possible, I gave it another go and updated my answer. Please try (works for me in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

But you can do it with many ways.
First you can remove the attribute "onclick".You can do it with javascript.

```js
$('.elem').removeAttr("onclick");

$('.elem').click(function () {
    alert('Whatever you want');
    alert('Huh?');
})
```

Here is a link: http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/javascript-events.html